# Add padding to Bootstrap by LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm adding padding 10px to div in bootstrap this way:

html:

```
<div class="span12 padded"></div>
```

my.less file:

```
.padded {padding: @gridGutterWidth/2;}
.span1.padded {width: (@gridColumnWidth * 1) + (@gridGutterWidth * 0) - @gridGutterWidth;}
.span2.padded {width: (@gridColumnWidth * 2) + (@gridGutterWidth * 1) - @gridGutterWidth;}
.span3.padded {width: (@gridColumnWidth * 3) + (@gridGutterWidth * 2) - @gridGutterWidth;}

... all other spans in same way
```

And this working without problem.
I'm trying to modify this to make this more universal now but can't get this to work:

html:

```
<div class="span12 padded20"></div>
```

my.less file:

```
@padding10 = 10px;
@padding20 = 20px;
@padding30 = 30px;
@padding40 = 40px;

.padded10 {padding: @padding10;}
.padded20 {padding: @padding20;}
.padded30 {padding: @padding30;}
.padded40 {padding: @padding40;}

.span1.padded10 {width: (@gridColumnWidth * 1) + (@gridGutterWidth * 0) - (@padding10 * 2);}
.span2.padded10 {width: (@gridColumnWidth * 2) + (@gridGutterWidth * 1) - (@padding10 * 2);}
.span3.padded10 {width: (@gridColumnWidth * 3) + (@gridGutterWidth * 2) - (@padding10 * 2);}

... same way for all spans and padding types
```

Why second way doesn't add any padding to span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:`, not `=` in variable assignments.

```
@padding10: 10px;
@padding20: 20px;
@padding30: 30px;
@padding40: 40px;
```

Generally, you can use [this compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) to check your `LESS` code.

Comment: @MariuszPoplawski Often mistakes are there you don't expect them at all. And then showing your code to someone else really helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using less you may as well let it do the work for you. Add this along with the other bootstrap less files. Include it after the bootstrap and responsive css. This may be extended to include fluid and offset layouts, but I do not use them.

```
// REPEAT VARIABLES
// -------------------------
// Required since we compile the responsive stuff separately
@import "variables.less"; // Modify this for custom colors, font-sizes, etc

// Padding mixin
.padding (@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth,@padding) {
    // PadX mixin accepting column numbers greater than zero
    .padX (@index) when (@index > 0) {

        // Write out the span number using escaping
        (~".span@{index}.padded@{padding}") { 
            // Call the .pad mixin below with the column number
            .pad(@index); 
        }

        // Decrement the index and calls itself again
        // This is the less version of a for loop
        .padX(@index - 1);
    }

    // Catch the zero valued index essentially terminating the loop
    .padX (0) {}    

    // Mixin for padding
    .pad(@columns) {
        width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columns) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columns - 1) 
                - (@padding * 2));
    }

    // This will be written out
    (~".padded@{padding}")  {
        // Trick to add px to the end of your padding
        padding: 0px+@padding;
    }

    // Call the padX mixin with gridColumns as starting value
    .padX(@gridColumns);
}

// grid.less overide
// -------------------------
// Call the padding mixin
.padding(@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth, 10);
.padding(@gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth, 20);

// responsive overides
// -------------------------
//Kill these if not using responsive
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  // Fixed grid
  .padding(@gridColumnWidth768, @gridGutterWidth768,10);
  .padding(@gridColumnWidth768, @gridGutterWidth768,20);
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  // Fixed grid
  .padding(@gridColumnWidth1200, @gridGutterWidth1200,10);
  .padding(@gridColumnWidth1200, @gridGutterWidth1200,20);
}
```

You may test it in this awesome [compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler), but you will need to paste variables.less content or required variables in place of the @import.